# I want to purchase a new Ubuntu installation CD

Tags: disk

Can you mail me a new Ubuntu instillation CD, please?  I want to switch from Windows and need an installation CD, please.  How much do you charge?  Can I send you a check,please, I do not trust online banking.

Comment: Go to [Canonical Store](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17) if you would like to purchase one. Anyway if you don't want to buy from here. you can [download Ubuntu Deskto](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) for free and create [Bootable DVD/USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) to install Ubuntu.

Comment: @souravc Please write up your comment as an answer. A better one doesn't seem likely (or even possible) in this instance. Let me know so I can upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: @ElderGeek thanks! I thought to write an answer but forgot later.

Comment: haha the simplest thing you can do is download  a [32](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=--&version=14.04&architecture=i386) or [64](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=CA&version=14.04&architecture=amd64) bit iso then burn it to a blank DVD that you bought or have :)
Also, since you seem new in this kind of thing. Search for how to make a bootable usb drive. It can save you money.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you mail me a new Ubuntu instillation CD?

In brief NO. [ShipIt](http://www.ubuntu.com/shipit) has been closed. So the there is no official way to send anybody Ubuntu DVD for free.

> What are the other options do I have?

- You can buy packs of 5 Ubuntu CDs (minimum) from [Canonical shop](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17)
- Alternately you can [download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) CD image from the official Ubuntu site for free and [create](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) Bootable DVD or USB
- The last option would be to borrow a Ubuntu DVD from a friend.

<sub>**Note:** I answered most of it in the [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381392/i-want-to-purchase-a-new-ubuntu-installation-cd?noredirect=1#comment486913_381392). I am posting it as answer as requested by  [Elder Geek](https://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek) and think it will be helpful.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can purchase Ubuntu from the site mentioned below:
[Canonical store](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17)

It is safe and sound from here. You can download multiple copies also or else download Ubuntu for free from the site mentioned here [Download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu can be downloaded for free from ubuntu (bellow) then burnt to DVD or USB

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/

Although there are sites that will charge you for the DVD, shipping and handling fee.